# Filter array of elements with new array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have function that return me result if I forward one parameter. Now, I want to change it, to can return results, by more than one parameter, if I forward array to return me all elements which has that array?
For example if I forward 'International' and 'Balkan', I want to get as a result restaurant1 and restaurant 3, cause they include this two type, and it if must to have both type, not or.
Also one more problem which I have here is if I change in last line of code, in console log 'Chinese' with category1, then code does not return result?

```js
 
function createRestaurant(name, address, averageMealPrice, numberOfTable, category, startTime, endTime) {
    return {
      name, 
      address, 
      averageMealPrice, 
      numberOfTable, 
      category,
      startTime,
      endTime
      };
}
  
function createCategory(type) {
  return {
    type 
  };
}


const category1 = createCategory('Chinese');
const category2 = createCategory('International');
const category3 = createCategory('Balkan');
const category4 = createCategory('Indian');



let restaurant1 = createRestaurant('Rosetto', 'Boulevar 2', 500, 71, ['Chinese', 'International', 'Balkan', 'Indian'], 8, 20);
let restaurant2 = createRestaurant('McDonalnds', 'Promenada', 300, 30, ['Indian', 'International'], 1, 21);
let restaurant3 = createRestaurant('Piknik', 'Iceland', 660, 40, ['Balkan', 'International'], 11, 22);

let restaurants = [restaurant1, restaurant2, restaurant3];

function findRestaurantsByCategory(restaurantsByCategory, category){
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < restaurantsByCategory.length; i++) {
    if (restaurantsByCategory[i].category.includes(category)) {
      result.push(restaurantsByCategory[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;

}

console.log(findRestaurantsByCategory(restaurants, 'Chinese'));
```

Comment: Your `category1` is an object like `{ type : 'Chinese' }`. So if you call `findRestaurantsByCategory` by passing this object. In `findRestaurantsByCategory`  `category = { type : 'Chinese' }` , So your `restaurantsByCategory[i].category.includes(category)` will never satisfy. It will compare like `['Chinese', 'International', 'Balkan', 'Indian'].includes({ type : 'Chinese' })`, which will never true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to change `findRestaurantsByCategory(restaurantsByCategory` function signature to accept multiple parameters. We can do it by using the [Rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) parameter.

Then inside `findRestaurantsByCategory` we will get `category` as an array, which contains all parameters excluding the first parameter.

So if we call `findRestaurantsByCategory(restaurants, 'Chinese', 'Indian', 'Balkan')` like this we will get `category = ['Chinese', 'Indian', 'Balkan']`.

```js
function createRestaurant(name, address, averageMealPrice, numberOfTable, category, startTime, endTime) {
    return {
      name, 
      address, 
      averageMealPrice, 
      numberOfTable, 
      category,
      startTime,
      endTime
      };
}
  
function createCategory(type) {
  return {
    type 
  };
}


const category1 = createCategory('Chinese');
const category2 = createCategory('International');
const category3 = createCategory('Balkan');
const category4 = createCategory('Indian');



let restaurant1 = createRestaurant('Rosetto', 'Boulevar 2', 500, 71, ['Chinese', 'International', 'Balkan', 'Indian'], 8, 20);
let restaurant2 = createRestaurant('McDonalnds', 'Promenada', 300, 30, ['Indian', 'International'], 1, 21);
let restaurant3 = createRestaurant('Piknik', 'Iceland', 660, 40, ['Balkan', 'International'], 11, 22);

let restaurants = [restaurant1, restaurant2, restaurant3];

function findRestaurantsByCategory(restaurantsByCategory, ...category){
  return restaurantsByCategory.filter(restaurantCat => isAllMatched(restaurantCat.category, category));
}

function isAllMatched(rCatogory, toBeMatchedCategory){
  for(let x =0; x < toBeMatchedCategory.length; x++){
    if(!rCatogory.includes(toBeMatchedCategory[x])){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(findRestaurantsByCategory(restaurants, 'Chinese', 'International', 'Balkan', 'Indian'));
//console.log(findRestaurantsByCategory(restaurants, 'Balkan', 'International'));
console.log(findRestaurantsByCategory(restaurants, 'Indian', 'International'));
```

Comment: @navanth Hi, thanks. But if I run snippet this will return all restaurants, I do not need all who has at least one of this category. If you forward Chinese, Indian, Balkan, I need only restaurants which has all of these three category, not at least one of them, which means result for Chinese, Indian and Balkan will be only restaurant 1...

Comment: @MAlex If we pass `'Chinese', 'International'` what will be result, considering above mentioned example.  Are you looking for an exact match or should have all provided categories

Comment: @navanth I am looking to both Chinese and International be included for example in restaurant1, not one of them.

Comment: @navanth This works for example for console.log(findRestaurantsByCategory(restaurants, 'Balkan', 'International'));             But if I add one more, for example 'Balkan', 'International', 'Indian'     I got empty array... But I should get restaurant1.

Comment: @MAlex I think this is it. Check now